# Distribution of a function of the mean of poisson iid sample.

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, poisson-distribution, order-statistics

I just want to make sure that my answer is correct.

---

I have $X_i \sim Poi(\lambda)$ and I need to find the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}-\lambda)$ as $n\to\infty$

---

Central Limit Theorem:

$$\sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{X}_n - \mu}{\sigma} \xrightarrow[]{\;\;\;D\;\;\;} Z\sim(0,1) $$

$\mu = \lambda$ and $\sigma^2 = \lambda$ so

$$\sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{x}_n - \lambda}{\sigma} \approx Z \implies 
\sqrt{n}(\overline{x}_n - \lambda) \approx Z\sigma
$$

and we know that $\mathbb{E}(Z) = 0$ so $\mathbb{E}(Z\sigma) = \sqrt\lambda \mathbb{E}(Z) = 0$ and $Var(Z\sigma) = 
\sigma^2Var(Z) = \lambda$ so in the end we have

$$\sqrt{n}(\overline{x}_n - \lambda) \sim N(0,\lambda)$$

Does this make sense?